# Why do I get error message in python that len is missing when I use the built in len function?

Tags: python, debugging

I am currently working on a python project - windows application / software that has GUI where you can put patient information and so on and all that is going to a local mysql database / table. all that works but my IDE VS code gives 4 error messages and one of the errors is related to "len()" function. I will provide Github link of the entire code plus the error messages so if someone can help, please do so! Thank you!

https://github.com/ethicalduty/Hospital_Management_Software_Windows/blob/main/main_Hospital_Management_Software_Windows_3.11.0.py

I am new to programming so I cannot do much besides trying to find similar solution on google. I have not found anything already resolved so far, thus asking for help here!

Comment: Please post just the piece of code that's causing the problem. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: there is no reason why a link to the code is needed ... add the actual code to your post

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "errors" you are seeing are type checking issues, not real Python errors that are occurring when you run your code. They're warnings that there *might* be real errors in the code, but you should be able to run it regardless and the code may work fine. Whether there's a real issue may depend on the data the code is processing (it might work for some kinds of data but not others), or there might be inaccuracies in how the type checker is interpreting the code (and so there is no real issue in the code at all).

The issue that has to do with `len` seems to be saying that your `rows = my_cursor.fetchall()` statement may assign `None` to `rows`, which would cause an error below where you do `len(rows)`. I don't know MySQL's Python bindings, so I'm not sure if the type checker's assumption is correct that a query could cause `fetchall` to return `None` (rather than an empty list), but if that's the case, you can easily fix the type checking issue (and the possibly small chance of a real error when you run the code) by checking that `rows` is not `None` before you check its length:

```
    rows = my_cursor.fetchall()
    if rows is not None and len(rows) != 0:
        ...
```

Comment: This was so helpful, knowing that I am only few months into coding it helps me improve my python computational logic and also the solution provided by Blckknght solved the actual "error", but unfortunately I lost the Update button function :(.  I am very thankful for the very fast response anyway! I may leave it for now as is because it works just fine.

Comment: Also I would like to thank Roger Lipscombe for the advice that I need not to link my git code but instead paste the code directly here, the part that is causing errors / problems, an also, jsotola, this is not a school project, it is personal project that finally works, only those 4 "errors" were a poke in my eye but as long as the software works as intended, I think I`ll skip them for now! Thank you once more to all!